# Why does this strange Python `array.append()` work?

Tags: python

Concerning inline comments #1 and #2 in the Python code below, it makes sense why #2 works, but why does #1 also work?

About #1, the `for` loop that updates `rounds` is after the `matches.append()`. Why does `matches` continue to update after?

```
teams_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0]
x = teams_list[0:int(len(teams_list)/2)]
y = teams_list[int(len(teams_list)/2):len(teams_list)]

matches = []

for i in range(len(teams_list)-1):
    rounds = {}
    print('i ', i)
    print('rounds top ', rounds)
    print('matches top ', matches)
    if i != 0:
        x.insert(1,y.pop(0))
        y.append(x.pop())
    matches.append(rounds) # 1) Why does this work?
    for j in range(len(x)):
        rounds[x[j]] = y[j]
    #matches.append(rounds) # 2) correct
    print('rounds bottom ', rounds)
    print('matches bottom ', matches)
for i in range(len(matches)):
    print('\n Day',i+1, ' : ', matches[i])
```

Output:

```
i  0
rounds top  {}
matches top  []
rounds bottom  {1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 0}
matches bottom  [{1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 0}]
i  1
rounds top  {}
matches top  [{1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 0}]
rounds bottom  {1: 5, 4: 0, 2: 3}
matches bottom  [{1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 0}, {1: 5, 4: 0, 2: 3}]
i  2
rounds top  {}
matches top  [{1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 0}, {1: 5, 4: 0, 2: 3}]
rounds bottom  {1: 0, 5: 3, 4: 2}
matches bottom  [{1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 0}, {1: 5, 4: 0, 2: 3}, {1: 0, 5: 3, 4: 2}]
i  3
rounds top  {}
matches top  [{1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 0}, {1: 5, 4: 0, 2: 3}, {1: 0, 5: 3, 4: 2}]
rounds bottom  {1: 3, 0: 2, 5: 4}
matches bottom  [{1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 0}, {1: 5, 4: 0, 2: 3}, {1: 0, 5: 3, 4: 2}, {1: 3, 0: 2, 5: 4}]     
i  4
rounds top  {}
matches top  [{1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 0}, {1: 5, 4: 0, 2: 3}, {1: 0, 5: 3, 4: 2}, {1: 3, 0: 2, 5: 4}]        
rounds bottom  {1: 2, 3: 4, 0: 5}
matches bottom  [{1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 0}, {1: 5, 4: 0, 2: 3}, {1: 0, 5: 3, 4: 2}, {1: 3, 0: 2, 5: 4}, {1: 
2, 3: 4, 0: 5}]

 Day 1  :  {1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 0}

 Day 2  :  {1: 5, 4: 0, 2: 3}

 Day 3  :  {1: 0, 5: 3, 4: 2}

 Day 4  :  {1: 3, 0: 2, 5: 4}

 Day 5  :  {1: 2, 3: 4, 0: 5}
```

Comment: When you did `matches.append(rounds)`, you appended *`rounds` itself* to the list - not a copy of it as it existed at that moment in time.  Further changes to `rounds` are visible via the element of `matches`, because they are simply two references to the same object.